# INSERT no Result Value

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert some value into my database, but I got no result, but the code got no error, and the result label said it is succeed. My database connection working. How to check the issue here, I confused.

**My Code Here**

```
// insert new data to menu table
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_jadwal (Nama_Lokasi, Category_ID, Longitude, Latitude, Phone, Email, Menu_image, Description)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$upload_image = 'upload/images/' . $menu_image;
$stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql_query))
{
     // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
     $stmt->bind_param('sssssss',
                     $nama_lokasi,
                     $category_ID,
                     $longitude,
                     $latitude,
                     $phone,
                     $email,
                     $upload_image,
                     $description
     );
     // Execute query
     $stmt->execute();
     // store result
     $result = $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` on your page and check for errors

Comment: Not sure how `$stmt->bind_param()` works when the numbers differ but you have 7 x `s` and you're passing 8 variables there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, you were missing one `s` in the param string

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss',
                    $nama_lokasi,
                    $category_ID,
                    $longitude,
                    $latitude,
                    $phone,
                    $email,
                    $upload_image,
                    $description
```

And you have way too much code. Only a very little part of it is relevant

Comment: hi thank you It is working now, but I don't understand with what you said way too much code? can you explain it a little bit further please, thank you very much

Comment: Of course :) Since your query is not working you should only post your query and the code where you execute it. All the HTML Code and the way on how you set your parameter are irrelevant to solve the query issue. I had to search for the part where your problem is because it is not highlighted and "hidden" in all these lines of code

Comment: I see. I'm sorry then, I will only put the relevant code someday. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant code. This should be enough to solve the problem :)